# react-navigation not working, props is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am building a POC application in react-native and trying to implement react-navigation

```
import {StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this)
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Home',
    };

    clicked = ()=> {
        this.props.navigator.navigate('DrawerOpen'); // open drawer
    }

    render() {
        // const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.container}>

                    <View style={styles.header}>
                        <View style={{width: 50}}>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> {
                                this.clicked("DrawerOpen")
                            }}>
                                <Image source={require('./img/hamburger_icon.png')}/>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>
                    </View>
               </View>
           </ScrollView >
       )
    }
 }
```

Now whenever I am clicking on touchable highlight, clicked function gets called and it shows error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigator.navigate')
clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

You try it :)

```
 import {StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

    export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

        static navigationOptions = {
            drawerLabel: 'Home',
        };

        clicked = () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); // open drawer
        }

        render() {
            // const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
            return (
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.container}>

                        <View style={styles.header}>
                            <View style={{width: 50}}>
                                <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>
                                    this.clicked()
                                }>
                                    <Image source={require('./img/hamburger_icon.png')}/>
                                </TouchableHighlight>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                   </View>
               </ScrollView >
           )
        }
     }
```

Comment: It is still showing 
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

Answer (score 0):

Try this , May be this can help you, Inside the clicked

```
clicked = ()=> {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. Only the top level components get the this.props.navigation.

Probably you have to call this component like this:

`<HomeScreen navigation=this.props.navigation />`